# Spark Serializer Kryo setRegistrationRequired(false)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, kryo

I'm using `weka.mi.MISVM` in a `Scala/Spark` program and need to serialize my kernels to reuse them later.

For this I use `Kryo` as this :

```
conf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
conf.registerKryoClasses(
    Array(classOf[Multiset], classOf[MISVM], classOf[(_,_)],
     classOf[Map[_,_]], classOf[Array[_]])
)

...

val patterns: RDD[(Multiset, MISVM)] = ...
patterns.saveAsObjectFile(options.get.out)
```

(Multiset is one of my objects)

The serialization works well but when I tried to read my kernels with:

`objectFile[(Multiset, MISVM)](sc, path)`

I obtain this error:

```
com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Encountered unregistered class ID: 13994
```

I think that it's because I don't have register all the classes used by MISVM and I read that `Kryo.setRegistrationRequired(false)` could be a solution but I don't understand how to use it in my case.

How to define that the `conf` `KryoSerializer` have to use `setRegistrationRequired(false)`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
conf.set("spark.serializer", org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
conf.set("spark.kryo.registrationRequired", "false")
```

Comment: Thanks I get an error notebook:1: error: not found: value conf . What needs to be imported?

Comment: @Sade conf here is spark's configuration, get it whatever way you get spark configuration. Something like spark().conf() or spark().configuration() or something like it